# Google chrome developer tools not showing source files

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, angular-cli

[image]

[image]

I am trying to debug my angular-cli project but source tab in google chrome developer tools is empty. In the "content script" section is "top" drop down menu visible which you can see on the picture and "google hangouts" which I don't understand why appears here, on the very bottom there is "js" folder which is empty. The same happens to all websites.
what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bug. Use https://crbug.com to find an existing report or submit a new one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

right click > inspect > setting > preferences >check Enable JavaScript source map checkbox